# Add a print button to a child window from the parent using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, parent-child, window.open

I am trying to add a print button to a newly opened window from the parent. What I have below works, but only when the alert is present. Comment it out and somecontent.html instantly overwrites the button.

I have tried the ready and load methods.  What am I missing?? and why?  Also help with attaching the onclick to the button and code to print the child's body would be most appreciated. I am new to JQuery
Here is my script:

```
    function addbutton()
    {
        alert("addbutton");
        $(childwindow.document.body).prepend('<input type="button" value="click me" >');
    }           

    childwindow=window.open("somecontent.html",'windowname', "width=400, height=400");

    $(childwindow).load(addbutton());
    //$(childwindow).ready(addbutton());
```

Comment: `$(childwindow).load(addbutton());` <-- that is calling addbutton and assigning what it returns to the event listener. So it in the end your code looks like `addbutton(); $(childwindow).load(undefined)`. Remove the `()`

Comment: So removing () gives us  $(childwindow).load(addbutton); Correct?  Which does not run the function at all ( the alert does not pop).  Thanks tho!

Comment: well that means jQuery load does not work for a pop up.